# how to dispatch symfony event without request

Tags: php, symfony, command

In my symfony project I have created a command for cron task(runs one time for day). It change a table and that table has updatedBy property (by doctrine blameable listener).
So i have to log a user programmatically. 
here is my code for that.

```
if ($this->container->get("security.context")->getToken() === null) {
      $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($systemUser, null, "admin_area", $systemUser->getRoles());
      $this->container->get("security.context")->setToken($token);
}
```

My problem is how to dispatch this event. Because there is no request I cant use following code.

```
$request = $this->container->get("request");
        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->container->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
```

Also get("request") service cannot use inside command.
Please help me to dispatch this event.

Answer (score 0):

-You can create a request object via the [create method](http://api.symfony.com/2.8/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method_create) as example:

```
$request = Request::create("?foo=bar");
```

Then use it in the event:

```
    $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
```

I don't know if need some params from the request but you can add (See the doc).

Hope this help

Comment: Problem is still there dear. First time i run the command, updatedBy field fill correctly. when i run that command again, updatedBy field fill by null.
then again if i run the command it fill  updatedBy field correctly. That happen iteratively. I thought that happen because i didn't dispatch. But i don't know exactly what is the problem.